# Where in xcode to set the watch app icon in "Watch" app showing on the iphone?

Tags: ios, watchos-2, watchos

I think i set up the new icons for my watch app in assets.xcassets. It looks fine everywhere expect for one place: the "Watch" app on my ios device.

When i open the Watch app on my iphone, on the left side where has all the watch apps you have is still showing the old icon.

Where should i set it?

Answer (score 2):

Set the watch icons in the `assets.xcassets` file that is in the Watch target - be careful *not* to use the one in the main iOS target nor the Watch Extention target.